# Select (TLS 1.3) Curves in Apache

Tags: apache, ssl, https, curve

I just upgraded my Apache to enable TLS 1.3. So far it works fine but TLS 1.3 ignores the "SSLOpenSSLConfCmd Groups" setting. So it uses weaker curves for TLS 1.3 than for TLS 1.2 and below. See: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=neuz.de&s=2a03%3a4000%3a6%3ae04d%3a0%3a0%3a0%3a1&latest

Any hints? Sure, the curves are OK but I prefer the best ones.

Also I'm not really happy with the Group selection for lower TLS versions. I currently use this config:

```
"SSLOpenSSLConfCmd Groups sect571r1:sect571k1:secp521r1:sect409k1:sect409r1:secp384r1:sect283k1:sect283r1:secp256k1:prime256v1:brainpoolP512r1:brainpoolP384r1:brainpoolP256r1"
```

What I would like to have is "use the strongest curves as preferred but never lower than 256bit".

Also for some curves listed by "openssl ecparam -list_curves" will not work. If I add brainpoolP512**t**1 (while brainpoolP512**r**1 works) to the list, Apache fails to start. Is there an easy way to find out which will work? Trial & Error is a bit annoying.

Comment: Which version of Apache? From documentation at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslopensslconfcmd you need at least Apache 2.4.8 and OpenSSL 1.0.2

Comment: 2.4.37. TLS1.3 was not enabled before that AFAIR. I know the SSLOpenSSLConfCmd but I can't find the correct options, neither in the OpenSSL nor the Apache documentation.

Comment: From https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/ssl/SSL_CONF_cmd.html#SUPPORTED-CONFIGURATION-FILE-COMMANDS, curves selection is done by the `Curves` keyword. I do not see the `Groups` keyword.

Comment: Curves and Groups are the same setting. There is no difference in behaviour if I replace Groups by Curves. I read somewhere that Groups is the newer Keyword but I currently can't find the Source.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. In TLS 1.3 the CLIENT sends the preferred curve. If this curve is in the list of accepted ones on the server, it will be used. If not, it will be re-negotiated. Most clients send 256bit curves which will be accepted in my config. If I remove all 256bit curves, stronger ones will be used.

"SSLOpenSSLConfCmd Groups sect571r1:sect571k1:secp521r1:sect409k1:sect409r1:secp384r1:brainpoolP512r1:brainpoolP384r1"

will solve the issue, however this will impact the compatibility.